# Access ngForm of parent in child

Tags: angular

I have a structure like this:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <div class=row>
    <app-section-a [myForm]="myForm"></app-section-a>
```

and my child component:

```js
@Component({
...
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
// ...
@Input() myForm: ElementRef;
```

```html
<input ...>
<button type=submit [disabled]="!myForm.valid">
```

and, this works perfectly to ensure that all the components in the form are counted for validity. The thing is, I don't think I should need to pass the reference to ngForm directly as an input. How do I skip that input and still make this work?

a detail: happens to be an angular 5 project.

Comment: if you're trying to build sub form I'd recommend checking https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form and this article https://dev.to/maxime1992/building-scalable-robust-and-type-safe-forms-with-angular-3nf9

Comment: I mean its already done. I just need this optimization

Comment: passing the form as an input is fine in my opinion. But you should not use `ElementRef` --> pass the `FormGroup`

Comment: @Riscie, I only need a element properties like validity .. if I create a formgroup, aren't I'm going to have to enforce that in all the child components? I definitely dont want to do all that. The reason I don't want to pass a reference at all is it adds unneccessary complexity to all child components. I want less technical debt in the design here.

Comment: I agree with @Riscie, passing the FormGroup is preferred. Or if you only need the validity, why don't you just pass the `valid` value, rather than the entire FormGroup

Comment: Have fun trying to find out what you did wrong then. But please *STOP* abusing tags. They aren't meant for visibility, they are meant to make finding questions and answers easier.

Comment: Panagiotis thank you for deleting those. You do not understand the purpose of a tag. Just because the solution to a problem isnt related to the tag doesnt mean that the problem isn't related to the tag. the common context of the problem is important.  More importantly, instead of fihgiting over tags when you have something to contribute, you could contribute and then ask me to revise my own post. Additionally, _localdb_ is commonly used in when developing an azure app in visual studio precisely because VS comes with SQL Server. So your answer in fact demonstrates the reason the tag is valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Complete working example in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsapi6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

**First of all** you do not need to pass `ngForm` to child component at all. Because you can tell child component is part of parent form group using `ControlContainer` and `NgForm` by providing to child-component providers array.

In this example one parent component `app.component` is loading child component with `*ngFor` and we just added `ControlContainer` to providers array of child component. Here, we just need to give different name for each child-component dynamically, for this purpose we need to pass index as `@Input()` to child component and assign it to `name` property of inputField.

If any of inputControl has error then, `submit` button of parent control is disabled.

**app.component.html** is...

```
<form #heroForm="ngForm" class="container">
   <div id="parent" *ngFor="let i of [0,1,2]"  >
      <app-child [id]="i+1" [name]="i+1" ></app-child>
   </div>
  <hr>
    {{heroForm.value | json}}
  <hr>
  <div>
     <app-button-submit></app-button-submit>
  </div>
</form>
```

**app-button-submit.html**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"
  [disabled]="!control.form.valid">Submit</button>
```

**We are binding**, `ControlContainer` directly to `[disabled]` state of button with dependency injection.. see below `constructor()` class file.

**app-button-submit.ts**

```
import {ControlContainer, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-button-submit',
   templateUrl: './button-submit.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./button-submit.component.css'],
   providers : [{provide : ControlContainer, useExisting : NgForm}]
})
export class ButtonSubmitComponent  {
   constructor(private control : NgForm) { }
}
```

**child-component.html**

```
<div class="form-group" >
   <label [for]="Name">Name</label>    
      <input type="text"  class="form-control"  [id]="id" required [(ngModel)]="vname" [name]="Name"  #names="ngModel">
        {{vname}}
   <div [hidden]="names.valid || names.pristine" class="alert alert-danger"> 
      Name is required  
   </div>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import {ControlContainer, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   ---,
   viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
 export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input('id') id;
   @Input ('name') Name;
 }
```

here, `ControlContainer` will take care of binding of `NgForm` of Parent-Component to Child-Component.

Comment: Thank you. I like your thinking... but the button for submit must, for these purposes, be in a child component, not the parent

Comment: Okay. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vsapi6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  Check out this updated link

Comment: `constructor(private control : NgForm) { }` this one line is all I needed (probably has to be public though). But I do appreciate how thorough your answer is, great answer!

Comment: Glad!! Answer is helpful to you.